# Access LinkedIn public profile by userName using REST APIs

Tags: json, api, linkedin-api, profile

We are working on a mobile application that fetches public profile of our company's employees. Although we have their LinkedIn user-name but still have to ask them to go to a specific page and sync their profiles with our app by authentication.  ( https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~?format=json )

I also have worked on accessing info without asking our employees to visit our app and authenticate using;

```
https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/id=pr61Fk_Yb_?format=json
```

And

```
https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.linkedin.com%2Fin%2Fbaqer-naqvi-32194649?format=json
```

Is there any else way to fetch the public profile ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just figured it out that I can search people using `people-search` API which is available only to partners.

**Query**

```
https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people-search:(people:(id,first-name,last-name,headline,picture-url,industry,positions:(id,title,summary,start-date,end-date,is-current,company:(id,name,type,size,industry,ticker)),educations:(id,school-name,field-of-study,start-date,end-date,degree,activities,notes)),num-results)?first-name=parameter&last-name=parameter
```